# Excel - Convert table into different format

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert a table from one format to another using VBA:

(The current original table is (17 rows by around 17000 columns)
Columns are added regularly and a row may be added or removed, thus it needs to be dynamic)

EXAMPLE OF Tables:

[image]

I have written a code that works fine for small examples, but it bombs out with larger sets, I had to split the code into 2 sections as I could not get it working otherwise, I am sure it can be done much better.

I have modified an example I found online, but the example was for a similar problem, not the same

```
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim cRng As Range
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim xOutRng As Range
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set cRng = Application.InputBox("Select Code Column", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Set rRng = Application.InputBox("Select Row from Code to last SKU", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Select your data", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Set outRng = Application.InputBox("Select cell A2 on next sheet", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Set xWs = Rng.Worksheet

    Dim Rng2 As Range
    Dim cRng2 As Range
    Dim rRng2 As Range
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set cRng2 = Application.InputBox("Select Date Column", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Set rRng2 = Application.InputBox("Select Row from date to last SKU", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Set Rng2 = Application.InputBox("Select your data", xTitleId, Type:=8)

    'Section 1
    k = 1
    xColumns = rRng.Column
    xRow = cRng.Row
    For i = Rng.Rows(1).Row To Rng.Rows(1).Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1
        For j = Rng.Columns(1).Column To Rng.Columns(1).Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1
            outRng.Cells(k, 2) = xWs.Cells(i, xColumns)
            outRng.Cells(k, 3) = xWs.Cells(xRow, j)
            outRng.Cells(k, 4) = xWs.Cells(i, j)
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i

    'Section 2
    k = 1
    xColumns2 = rRng2.Column
    For i = Rng.Rows(1).Row To Rng.Rows(1).Row + Rng.Rows.Count - 1
        For j = Rng.Columns(1).Column To Rng.Columns(1).Column + Rng.Columns.Count - 1
            outRng.Cells(k, 1) = xWs.Cells(i, xColumns2)
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: Basically, you are trying to create an entirely new table from an existing one. If so, what are your criteria for the additional rows? In your example it appears that each row in table A gets an additional row in table B for every value in columns Item B and C. Is the target table always the same? If not there is hardly any way to create this dynamically

Comment: Thanks for the response, 

The target Table will always just have the 3 columns as in the example. The original may have more columns and definitely more rows.

In short Column A and B is duplicated for Each Column thereafter. E.g. 
Copy and Paste Colum A and B and then copy and paste Column C next to it.
Then Copy and Paste Colum A and B again below the previous and then copy and paste Column D next to it. 
Then Copy and Paste Colum A and B again below the previous and then copy and paste Column E next to it. 

Let me know if this is unclear, English is not my first language

Comment: From your example, it seems like a simple **unpivot** operation, easily done with `Power Query` aka `Get & Transform` and available in Excel 2010+

Comment: Thank you  Ron Rosenfeld, that is exactly what I needed, didn't know power query has the function, I was already creating the original table from Power Query.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still looking for a vba solution, this as a concept:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyTable()

    Dim rngValues As Range
    Dim rngValueColumns As Range
    Dim rngTarget As Range

    Dim varCell As Variant
    Dim varColumn As Variant
    Dim intNumberOfRows As Integer
    Dim intRowCounter As Integer
    Dim arrTarget() As Variant


    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ExampleTable")
        ' 1. Define value range (You will have to adjust this to your value range)
        Set rngValues = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))


        ' 2. Get all value columns
        Set rngValueColumns = Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    End With

    ' 3. Dimension target array. Should number of rows * number of value columns to 3 columns
    intNumberOfRows = rngValues.Rows.Count * rngValueColumns.Columns.Count

    ReDim arrTarget(1 To intNumberOfRows, 1 To 3)

    ' 3. Build an array of your target table in memory. Loop over each extra column and add rows.
    intRowCounter = 1
    For Each varColumn In rngValueColumns
        For Each varCell In rngValues
            arrTarget(intRowCounter, 1) = varCell.Value
            arrTarget(intRowCounter, 2) = varCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            arrTarget(intRowCounter, 3) = varCell.Offset(0, varColumn.Column - 1).Value
            intRowCounter = intRowCounter + 1
        Next varCell
    Next varColumn

    ' 4. Define target range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ExampleTable2")
        Set rngTarget = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(arrTarget, 1), UBound(arrTarget, 2)))
        rngTarget = arrTarget
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Unpivot is working great, but I will definitely have a look at the VBA solution you suggested for interest sake once I have some time, thank you!